# How to do functional-component relationship in c#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

How is the proper way to declare a class that needs another class to be functional?

For example,

```
public class Car
{
    IEngine Engine { get; set; }
}

interface IEngine
{
    void go();
}

public class DieselEngine
{
    void go() {}
}
```

The Car class defines the majority of the functionality of the object. However some of the functionality is delegated to a sub-object, which supports some interface.

Is this the right way to do it? Should I make the Car abstract? or the Engine? or both? Perhaps I should ditch the IEngine and make DieselCar a subclass?

```
public class Car
{
    abstract void go();
}

public class DieselCar : Car
{
    void go() {}
}
```

what other ways can I accomplish this? and which is the best one?

Comment: If you're going to have multiple types of `Car` then yes, this one way you can accomplish this. You can then implement a Abstract Factory design pattern to maximize the inheritance. What's best is really up to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern)

The issue with deriving classes is what if you have additional parameters.  For example, if you had 2-door and 4-door cars, through derivation you might have 4 classes now:

- DieselFourDoorBodyCar
- GasFourDoorBodyCar
- DieselTwoDoorBodyCar
- GasTwoDoorBodyCar

You can see that this will quickly spin out of control with additional properties.  The abstract factory is a way to specify different exchangeable components for your classes that are constructed through some type of builder specification.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
public interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}

public class Engine : IEngine
{
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        // Do the common start here
        IsRunning = true;
    }
}

public class DieselEngine : Engine
{
    public void Start()
    {
        // Do some deisel start stuff here
        WaitForGlowPlug();

        // Now start
        base.Start();
    }

    private void WaitForGlowPlug()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Car
{
    private IEngine _engine;

    public IEngine Engine
    {
        get { return _engine; }
        set { if (value != null) _engine = value; }
    }

    public Car()
    {
        Engine = new Engine();
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    Car dieselCar = new Car
    {
        Engine = new DieselEngine()
    };

    dieselCar.Engine.Start();
}
```

But really, you need to look at what makes a Diesel Car different than another Car. If it's more than the engine, then you might want to make a base Car class (or ICar interface) and have a DieselCar class that inherits from Car. Depends on how granular you want to get.

Comment: What if I don't want to allow a Car with Engine=null?  What is the best way to prevent that?

Comment: One way would be to make it a property, set it to some default value in the constructor, and in the set code don't allow a null value. I updated the class to reflect this comment.

Comment: Another way would be to develop a set of builder methods that enforce construction of a valid object by hiding the constructor from the public API.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. I find constructors the best way to constrain the creation of a class and also convey to the user of the class what it needs to be 'functional':

```
public Car(IEngine engine)
{
    Contract.Requires(engine != null;
}
```

From here, control can be exerted via a read-only property or a Get with validation.

I think the most interesting point about the question you raise is how to design the class so that you convey its requirements clearly and intuitively.